# How to conditionally replace text in a list with regex_replace?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I have a variable in my playbook that's derived from a list. In some instances this variable contains a "-" to separate two values. For example,

```
Numbers:
  - 2211
  - 2211-2212
```

When this is the case I would like to replace the "-" with a "_" based on a conditional: If the number is 4 characters long, do this. Else, replace the "-" with a " _ " and do that.

I've already tried to fiddle around with jinja2 ans regex in my playbooks but so far no luck. Here's what I tried,

```
number: {% if length(item) == 4 %} {{ item | regex_replace("^(.*)$", "Number_\1") | string }} {% else %} {{ item | regex_replace("^(.*)$", "Number_\1") |replace("-", "_") | string }}
```

The result that I would like to have,

```
Number is four characters long:
    number: Number_2211
Number is more then 4 characters long:
    number: Number_2211_2212
```

Some of the Error messages I have received are,

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key
```

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found character that cannot start any token
```

Is there a way to achieve this within the Ansible playbook?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear how you're trying to use this data.  Ansible isn't great at *modifying* complex data structures in place, but it has lots of way of transforming data *when you access it*.  So for example, this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    numbers:
      - "2211"
      - "2211-2212"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "number: {{ item.replace('-', '_') }}"
      loop: "{{ numbers }}"
```

Will output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=2211) => {
    "msg": "number: 2211"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=2211-2212) => {
    "msg": "number: 2211_2212"
}
```

If you really need to make the transformation conditional on the length (and it's not clear that you do), you could do something like:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.replace('-', '_') if item|length > 4 else item }}"
  loop: "{{ numbers }}"
```

**Update**

I see you've selected the other answer.  The solution presented here seems substantially simpler (there is no "incomprehensible sequence of filters, regex expressions, and equality checks"), and produces almost identical output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=445533) => {
    "msg": "445533"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=112234-538) => {
    "msg": "112234_538"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=11) => {
    "msg": "11"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1111) => {
    "msg": "1111"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1111-1111) => {
    "msg": "1111_1111"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=11-11) => {
    "msg": "11_11"
}
```

It's not clear, given `11-11`, whether you expect `11_11` or `11-11` as output. If you expect the former, this answer is more correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me get it right!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an incomprehensible sequence of filters, regex expressions, and equality checks to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
- name: Lets munge some data
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: false
  vars:
    array:
    - 445533
    - 112234-538
    - 11
    - 1111
    - 1111-1111
    - 11-11
  tasks:
  - name: Replace hypens when starting with 4 numbers
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ((item | string)[0:4] | regex_search('[0-9]{4}') | string != 'None') 
             | ternary((item | regex_replace('-', '_')), item) }}"
    loop: "{{ array }}"

PLAY [Lets munge some data] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Replace hypens when starting with 4 numbers] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=445533) => {
    "msg": "445533"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=112234-538) => {
    "msg": "112234_538"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=11) => {
    "msg": "11"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1111) => {
    "msg": "1111"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=1111-1111) => {
    "msg": "1111_1111"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=11-11) => {
    "msg": "11-11"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```